# DAO initialising integer to 0 when loading

Tags: java, netbeans, dao

When my system loads the text file with the data already in it,it always initialises the integers for restaurantTables and restaurantSeats to 0? How do I stop this from happening and keep the figures assigned when adding to the system?

Here is the code which changes it back to 0:

public class TextRestaurantDAO extends RestaurantDAO {
        static final char DELIMITER=':';

```
@Override
public List<Restaurant> loadRestaurants(Path path) {
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();   
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.toString())))) {         
        s.useDelimiter(Character.toString(DELIMITER));
        Restaurant r;
        int restaurantId, restaurantTables, restaurantSeats;
        String restaurantName, restaurantLocation;


        while (s.hasNext()) {
            if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                restaurantId = s.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                restaurantId = 0;
            }

           if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                restaurantTables = s.nextInt();

            }
                else {
                    restaurantTables = 0;
            }
           if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                restaurantSeats = s.nextInt();

            }
                else {
                    restaurantSeats = 0;
            }

            restaurantName = s.next();
            restaurantLocation = s.next();
            s.nextLine();
            r = new Restaurant(restaurantId, restaurantName, restaurantLocation, restaurantTables, restaurantSeats);
            restaurants.add(r);
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TextCustomerDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
    return restaurants;
}


@Override
public void storeRestaurants(Path path, List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
    try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(path.toFile())) {
        for (Restaurant r:restaurants) {
            output.println(toFileString(r));
        }
        output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TextRestaurantDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}

public String toFileString(Restaurant r) {
    return  Integer.toString(r.getRestaurantId()) + DELIMITER +
            r.getRestaurantName() + DELIMITER +
            r.getRestaurantLocation() + DELIMITER +
            r.getRestaurantTables() + DELIMITER +
            r.getRestaurantSeats() + DELIMITER;
}    

}
```

If you could help it would be much appreciated.

Here is an example of what the text file has before it loads:
1:Riva:Bothwell:31:78:

After it Loads:
1:Riva:Bothwell:0:0:

How do i stop this from happening?

Thankyou

*if you require more code please ask*

Comment: Try to move 
            restaurantName = s.next();
            restaurantLocation = s.next(); after the first if else
the s.hasNextInt() returns false because 2nd token is Riva and it's not an integer.

Comment: @user3758745Thank you!